# Increment numerical value in InstallAnywhere

Tags: batch-file, counter, installanywhere

I have a question for those of you who have worked with InstallAnywhere:

I essentially have written a while loop in an InstallAnywhere project.  What I would like to find is an easy and simple way to implement a counter inside this "While loop".  Here is some pseudo code of my attempt:

```
Set InstallAnywhere Variable: $COUNT$ = 0
Jump Label: while
Execute Script/Batch File:
    @echo off
    set /a TEMP_NUM=$COUNT$+1 > nul
    echo %TEMP_NUM%
Set InstallAnywhere Variable: $COUNT$ = $EXECUTE_STDOUT$
Jump: while    Rule: $COUNT$ [Less Than or Equal to] 100
```

The above code sets $COUNT$ to the following:

```
Loop 0:
    1
Loop 1:
    1
Loop 2:
    1
...
```

I wonder if this happens because InstallAnywhere is replacing $COUNT$ inside the batch file with 0 in the first loop, and then in subsequent loops it re-uses the same batch file with $COUNT$ already substituted in (like in a batch for loop or if statement).

Comment: It looks like you're never actually incrementing the `$COUNT$` variable in this loop. Instead you're setting `$TEMP_VAR$` to equal `$COUNT$+1` - so `$COUNT$` never actually changes. Though I haven't worked with InstallAnywhere.

Comment: Is the `Set InstallAnywhere Variable: ...` line setting `$COUNT$` to the output of the `Execute Script/Batch File:` line? If so, this looks like it should work. However, again, I haven't used InstallAnywhere, so I don't understand how variables are handled.

Comment: Yes, InstallAnywhere allows you to create "actions" and you just fill in the details. There is an action that executes whatever you type into the Text Area and stores the output in a variable ($EXECUTE_STDOUT$). I am unsure how these actions are implemented except that they are implemented using java. It could be that the Text Area that holds the batch code is saved to a batch file with the InstallAnywhere variables substituted in and then when the action is executed again, it just reruns the saved batch file instead of recreating it.  That would mean my solution would not work.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that $COUNTS$ should be accessed from the OS ENV table using the special key $lax.nl.env.counts$ ? per docs,

> You can access any System Environment variable (for example, access
>   path via $lax.nl.env.path$) by specifying the property name as an
>   all-lowercase string. These properties are resolved at application
>   runtime, when LaunchAnywhere executes. You can also get access to
>   System Environment variables via InstallAnywhere variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just added some line numbers to your code:

> 1. Set InstallAnywhere Variable: $COUNT$ = 0
> 2. Jump Label: while
> 3. Execute Script/Batch File:
> 4. @echo off
> 5. set /a TEMP_NUM=$COUNT$+1 > nul
> 6. echo %TEMP_NUM%
> 7. Set InstallAnywhere Variable: $COUNT$ = $EXECUTE_STDOUT$
> 8. Jump: while    Rule: $COUNT$ [Less Than or Equal to] 100

In line 5 and 6, what you are essentially doing is: **echo $COUNT$+1**

In  line 7, you are setting COUNT to $EXECUTE_STDOUT$ ( which is usually 0, I believe? )
That would explain why it prints 1 everytime because $COUNT$ gets set to 0 at the end of each loop.